# What is input and data parameters in tf.Print function?

Tags: tensorflow, printing

There are `input` and `data` parameters in [tf.Print function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print). What do they mean? I don't understand this from documentaion.

Suppose I wish to print tensor `A`. Should I pass it as `input`, `data`, both or someother way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tf.Print` acts like `tf.identity`, so it acts like `input=tf.identity(input)`, that is meaning of parameters `input`,
and `data: A list of tensors to print out when op is evaluated`, which means when we run the `input`, the `data` will be evaluated and the results will be printed.

When you want to run op `A` and print the op `B,C`, you should use `A=tf.Print(A, [B,C])` and then run `sess.run(A)`

Comment: Suppose I wan't to print just `A`, not any `B` or `C`.

Comment: You just use `A` instead of  `B,C`, which means `A=tf.Print(A, [A])`