# Does input_ parameter matter to tf.Print?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read the description for the parameter `input_` of `tf.Print` in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print). I tried a couple of experiments and got the results makes me so confused.

I used this following code to experiment

```
A = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a1, a2 = tf.split(A, 2, axis=0)
p = tf.Print(A, [a1, a2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([p])
```

Output

`[[1 2 3]][[4 5 6]]`

I have replaced the line of code `p = tf.Print(A, [a1, a2])` with `p = tf.Print(a1, [a1, a2])` or `p = tf.Print(a2, [a1, a2])` and got exactly the same output: `[[1 2 3]][[4 5 6]]`. This makes me feel that "*it does not matter what `input_` is, you can pass whatever you want*"

My questions are

1. Does `input_` parameter matter to `tf.Print`?
2. If it does, could you guys suggest me an example?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46647760/5657159), but IMO it does not cover the aspect what I wonder in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it matters. In your example the value of p will be input_ after the print op is run.

```
A = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a1, a2 = tf.split(A, 2, axis=0)
p = tf.Print(A, [a1, a2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    p_val = sess.run([p])

print(p_val)
```

This will illustrate the difference.

Also importantly, if p is not part of the actual graph computation it will not print the value. Therefore _input should be part of something you actually need to compute.

In practice just call

```
_input = tf.Print(_input,[...])
```

so it is a passthrough.